# d3 transition on tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, transition

I have a multi line chart where each point on mouseover displays a tooltip. On mouse out the tooltip disappears with some transition effect. The transition works on mouseover but does not on mouse out. Here is the code snippet

```
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    to_graph.forEach(function(d) {
          svg.selectAll("dot")
              .data(d.data)
              .enter()
              .append("svg:circle")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .attr("cx", function(v) {
                  return x(v[0]);
              })
              .attr("cy", function(v) {
                  return y(v[1]);
              })
              .attr("stroke", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", "2")
              .attr("fill", "white")
              .on("mouseover", function(v) {
                  div.transition()
                      .duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", '.9');
                  var text = formatTime(v[0]) + "<br/>" + v[1] + "<br/>" + d.label;
                  div.html(text)
                      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX)+"px")
                      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px")
                      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
                      //.style("opacity", '.9'); <---- NOT USEFUL
              })
              .on("mouseout", function() {
                  console.log(div);       // <----- div is defined
                  div.transition().duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", "0");
                  //d3.select(this)
                    //  .attr("fill", "transparent");
              });
      });
```

I might be missing something very obvious here. When I remove the transition on mouseout, it works but with the transition it does not.

Thanks!

Here is the full (simplified) graph code:

```
// general format
var graph_data = {"data": [y1, y2, ...], "alerts": [null, y2, null, y3...]};

// establish margin and padding

  var margin = {
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0
  };
  var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var xpadding = 70,
      ypadding = 70;

  // svg to hold the graph
  var svg = d3.select("#"+container)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // x-axis scale and min-max values
  var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([xpadding, width-xpadding*2])
      .domain([dateFrom, dateTo]);

        // y-axis scale and min-max values
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height-ypadding, ypadding])
      .domain([
          0,
          d3.max(graph_data.data)
      ]);

  // xaxis
  var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

  // yaxis
  var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - xpadding) + ")")
      .call(xaxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + ypadding + ",0)")
      .call(yaxis);

// points and tooltips on the chart for mouseover
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // draw alerts as dots
  var formatTime = d3.time.format("%a %e %B %I %p");
  var plot_data = formatData(graph_data.alerts, dateFrom);
  // filter out null values in alerts
  plot_data = plot_data.filter(function (d) {
      return d[1] !== null;
  });
  svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(plot_data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", function(v) {
          return x(v[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(v) {
          return y(v[1]);
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .on("mouseover", function(v) {
          div.transition()
              .duration(200)
              .style("opacity", 0.9);
          var text = "Alert<br/>"+ formatTime(v[0]) + "<br/>" + v[1];
          div.html(text)
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX)+"px")
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px")
              .attr("fill", "steelblue")
              .style("opacity", 0.9);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
          console.log(div);
          div.transition().duration(200)
              .style("opacity", 0);
      })
```

Comment: Have you tried giving numbers instead of strings to `opacity`, i.e. `.9` and `0` instead of `".9"` and `"0"`?

Comment: tried it and the tooltip is still lurking.

Comment: i have very similar code working for another page and that works. for this piece, there are no errors in console and the mouseout trigger works. so weird.

Comment: Hmm, could you provide a complete example where this happens?

Comment: I cant reproduce the simplified version of the problem in jsfiddle but I can in my codebase. Let me paste it here

Comment: I am not sure how much this will help. Is there a way I can debug if the transition is activated?

Comment: When a transition is active, the element should have a `.__transition__` attribute.

Comment: thank you for being so prompt with your replies. Appreciate your help.

Comment: there is a __transition__ array getting created and its size increases with each call. Its "active" property is always 0 though if that means something.

Comment: also, the transition does not work for mouseover as well. There is a div.html line thats setting the opacity which is why i thought it worked.

Comment: I set up a [D3 Tooltip Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9CzL/) to get a working example of your code. The basic axis are drawn. Two issues: 1. code still missing formatData() function, 
2. more realistic data would be nice, maybe you can update this and place the link to jsfiddle demo in your question too.

Comment: here we go - http://jsfiddle.net/Xh2vj/. This is simplified with only the alert points (its a multi line chart with alert points) The simplified version does not run in my code but does in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

I slightly updated your demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Xh2vj/1/ and have set transition time to 1000ms to easier recognise the animation. Tooltip fade in and fade out - it works for me:

[image]

Did not changed much, but removed the 'instant pop up' at mouseover:

```
      .on("mouseover", function(v) {
             div.transition()
                  .duration(1000) //longer to easier be seen
                  .style("opacity", 0.9); //this is for the tooltip
              var text = "Alert<br/>"+ formatTime(v[0]) + "<br/>" + v[1];
              div.html(text)
                  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX)+"px")
                  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px")
                  .attr("fill", "steelblue");
                 // .style("opacity", 0.9); // not here
          })
```

Tested on latest Desktop Browsers as Chrome 35, Safari 7 and Firefox 29. 
Older Opera 12 struggles with mouse over, maybe the tooltip overlays the point and therefore the mouse over does not count anymore. What browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114. Yeah i have tried varying durations with very small and large values.. still wont work! the mouse over/out events are triggered.. i have tested it with breakpoints. The div's __transition__ array count increases too. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: also note, that the jsfiddle code works for me. it doesn't work in my codebase.. not sure if its conflicting with other charts now.

Comment: So there might be some interferences with other D3 stuff and I just can guess with this information. For me, often diagrams misbehave, when I use wrong selectors or maybe overwrite a definition from another place. Check that there is no other selector and definitions for _d3.select("#"+container).append("svg")_ in your codebase (or at least the page containing this diagram and far more scripts...).

Comment: To check, if somewhat overwrites your svg-container.mouseover try
`.on("mouseover", function(v) { console.log('mouseover at '+ container+ ' with ' + v[0]);    div.transition...`. Hopefully there is just one mouse over defined. Just to be sure.

Comment: makes sense. to give you a basic idea - i have 5 pages with d3 but they are not sharing code or importing scripts as of now. Also there is one d3 graph per page. i changed the graph container name to be unique to this problem page.

Comment: console.log('mouseover at...') works giving the right value for the point. weird thing is if i just do `.on("mouseover", function(v) { div.style("opacity", 0.9);...` it works. Only with the transition added it does not. (I might just give up and use no transitions :()

Comment: I'm sorry, but I ran out of ideas. Anything by now would be guessing.